# Make Textview Visible by Pressing a Button

Tags: java, android, button, textview, onclicklistener

I have my first class assignment in android app programming, hopefully you guys could help with this.

I need to connect a code to a button so when I press it my textview will appear.

In my XML-file I have

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="@string/ok_knappen" 
    android:textColor="@color/button_dark_text"
    android:onClick="b"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/Beskrivning"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

In my Activity I have

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

No errors occurred. My text is invisbile but when I click the button nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised that you did not get an error - try removing this `android:onClick="b"`  This sets the onClickListener to be a method named `b` which does not exist.

Comment: And if you try your xml without `android:visibility="invisible"`, is your textview visible ?

Answer (score 2):

In TextView add:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

In Java code:

```
public void b(View view) {

    EditText numerField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView  tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //do sth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your textView given by

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **onClick** attribute from the Button.

The onClick attribute should be followed by a method. This method "b" does not exist, but since you have set the onClickListener in your code it does not seem necessary here I think.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onClick entry in the XML, or create a method with the signature "public void b(View v)" in your activity. The assignment of the onClick in the XML tries to find a method with that kind of listener. It is possible that the XML is overriding the Java assigning of the onClick listener.